# Как подсчитать время выполнения скрипта js?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Всем привет, я тут мучаюсь с одним скриптом, где по клику вызывается функция, попробовал поместить в промис:

```
$('.csv').on('click', async function ()
{
let start = new Date.getTime()
        let promiseScript = new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
        {

            // мой код...
        }
          resolve("done");
        });
let end = new Data.getTime()
        await promiseScript.then(document.querySelector('.description').innerHTML += `<span>На выполнение скрипта
 ушло ${end - start} ms</span>`);


            });
```

Но проблема в том, что он выводит **сначала** время выполнения скрипта, а уж только потом начинает выполнять скрипт.
Как можно корректно измерить время выполнения этого срипта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функцию `promiseScript` лучше объявлять через `const` так как Вы ее не меняете. Для того чтобы были заметны миллисекунды > 0 я добавил вывод в консоль и очистку, это занимает какое-то время.

Так как мы высчитываем в ней `start` и `end` то мы можем передать их вовне через `resolve` и без проблем получить их в `then` через `дестурктуризацию`:

Для лучшей структуры кода и пере использования я создал отдельную функцию для замера времени `measureTime`, так же тестируемую функцию `testFinction` и обработчик клика на кнопке запускающий тест.

```js
// функция замера времени
// func - тестируемая функция
const measureTime = func => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let start = (new Date).getTime()
  func() // вызываем тестируюмую функцию
  const end = (new Date).getTime()
  resolve([start, end]);
})

// какая-то тестируемая функция
const testFinction = () => {
  // мой код...
  console.log('')
  console.clear() // очищаем консоль
}

document.querySelector('.csv').onclick = async function (){
  // замеряем время testFinction
  const [start, end] = await measureTime(testFinction)
  // выводим результат
  document.querySelector('.description').innerHTML += 
  `<span>На выполнение скрипта  ушло ${end - start} ms</span></br>`
};
```

```html
<button class="csv">Произвести замер</button>
<p class="description"></p>
```

Comment: для чего тогда вообще передавать старт и энд когда можно их непосредственно  и вывести сразу в блок description, а не пропихивать через resolve наружу? Смысл данной задачи как раз в том чтобы человек понял как работают async/await и ошибка заключалась в том чтобы время завершения было внутри конструкции await..then

Comment: @IvaMuxa поправил код, надеюсь так лучше

Comment: это однозначно премия. с меня +1